# lfind gives inconsistent results

Tags: c

i'm trying to search a large array of structs using the first element of struct as the key. since the array is sorted, bsearch is fine and works for me. then i tried to use lfind to double-check the results but it gave me some weird output. the code is as follows, the correct output should be all hit as the key matches the 2nd element in the array. bsearch produced the correct results but lfind gave a mix of hits and misses. on misses, it seems that lfind didn't even call my compare function, which indicates some kindof error occured inside lfind. i tried using lldb to step into lfind but it shows assembly codes that i can't understand. if i reset void *hit = NULL before call to lfind, it seemed to solve the problem. but why? machine is MAC OS X Yosemite.

```
typedef struct SKU{
    char *sku;
    char *desc;
} SKU;

int SKUcmp(const void *, const void *);
int find_desc(const void *, const void *);

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    SKU skus[] = {
        {"", "080686002123"},                  
        {"000020", "Oyster Bay Pinot Gris"},         
        {"000122", "Woodstock Honey 12X250ml Cans"}, 
        {"000238", "Entertainers Cocktail Set"},     
        {"000987", "Hennessy VSOP 750ml"},           
        {"000988", "V Drink 355ML Cans"},            
        {"000989", "Dark Horse 7% 4x6x250ML Cans"}  
    };

    SKU dummy = {"000122", ""};
    void *hit;
    printf("binary search ... ");
    hit = bsearch(&dummy, skus, 7, sizeof(SKU), &find_desc); 
    if(hit) printf("HIT\n");
    else printf("MISS\n");

    // hit = NULL; // seemed to solve the problem
    int x = 7;
    printf("linear search ... ");
    hit = lfind(&dummy, skus, (size_t *)&x, sizeof(SKU), &find_desc); 
    if(hit) printf("HIT\n");
    else printf("MISS\n"); 
}

int find_desc(const void *key, const void *s){
    //printf("entering compare func ...\n");
    char *temp2 = ((SKU *)s)->sku;
    char *temp1 = ((SKU *)key)->sku;

    int result = strcmp(((SKU *)key)->sku, ((SKU *)s)->sku);

    return result;
}
```

run x10 produces the following output:

```
binary search ... HIT
linear search ... MISS
binary search ... HIT
linear search ... HIT
binary search ... HIT
linear search ... MISS
binary search ... HIT
linear search ... MISS
binary search ... HIT
linear search ... HIT
binary search ... HIT
linear search ... MISS
binary search ... HIT
linear search ... HIT
binary search ... HIT
linear search ... HIT
binary search ... HIT
linear search ... HIT
binary search ... HIT
linear search ... MISS
```

Comment: Please provide exact conditions (list of input keys, the way for calling your comparisons multiple times). Current posted code provides correct results with current your key and with several other keys that I have tried. Is it possible that posted code is slightly different from tested by you original code?

Comment: So you hate your compiler, or why do you use `void *`?

Comment: @OrestHera
cc -g -O0 lfinderr.c
then execute the bash script
 ! /bin/bash
 i=0;
 while [ $i -lt 10 ]
 do
     ./a.out
      i=`expr $i + 1`
 done

Comment: @Olaf i should've used cast. but don't think that's the reason code is not working.

Comment: No, you should've use proper types. And you should never cast `void *` in C.

Comment: @Olaf lfind returns void *, needs to be cast into SKU * had i used it? that's what i meant. sorry.

Comment: I give up! You either do not understand or don't want to. Did you even read my comments or just respond to trigger words?

Comment: @lche059 It looks very bad if calling the same binary leads to different results. Are we talking about the same code? I just did copy and past and also added required #include's: `stdlib.h`, `stdio.h`, `string.h`, `search.h`. Can you check this? It works as expected. Now I cannot test it on OS X Yosemite, however it is hard to believe that there is such serious library bug. Random result mean that some uninitialized  variable is used or stack is corrupted. There is nothing like that in the above code. You do not have to set `hit=NULL;` before calling `lfind`.

Comment: @lche059 Why do you use `int x = 7;` and cast instead of `size_t x = 7;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On OS X `sizeof(int) == 4` and `sizeof(size_t) == 8`.
It is a bug to cast `(int*)` to `(size_t*)`.

Probably that setting `hit = NULL` clears bytes on stack that are also used as array size after cast `(size_t*)`. So, it changes the application behavior.

However, the type of `x` should be `size_t`:

```
size_t x = 7;
```

Comment: that worked. thanks. the reason i used int is probably i thought it's only a small constant number for testing and the cast should be safe, 32-bit address to 64-bit address. i still don't understand why it's a bug. i've got a freebsd box where i'm sure int is also of 4-byte. i'll test it later to see if it causes the same problem. but yeah i should've used the right type specified by the function.

Comment: @lche059 If you dereference pointer to `size_t` it is assument that the variable size is 8 bytes, however you pass pointer to 4 bytes interger. So, derefernced size in `lfind` is invalid.

Comment: that made sense. and i tested it on the freebsd box and got the same problem. so you're right. so thanks for the help. i don't see the option. i tried to upvote but can't because i'm new.